# How to set MP and TS flags of register CR0? x86 Fasm

Tags: assembly, fasm

How to set MP and TS flags of register CR0?

I only know how To set PE flag:

```
mov eax, cr0
or eax, 1
mov cr0, eax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this Wikipedia article about Control Registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_register#CR0) and set the bits accordingly. In your case, starting from 0, the MP bit is at position 1 and the TS bit at position 3.

So you can use the following code to set the MP and TS flags in CR0:

```
mov eax, cr0
or  eax, 10      ; 2^1(MP) + 2^3(TS) = 2 + 8 = 10 decimal
mov cr0, eax
```

Comment: Thank you very much!